# How to get <img> content-type using javascript after loading

Tags: javascript, image, mime-types

In my HTML document, there is a image

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1d9c87a4d5cbcae4c76e867cb6861fa0?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
```

When open this document in browser, E.g. Chrome, we can find the `Content-Type` of this image is `"image/png"` in Chrome Developer Tools -> Network tab according to the HTTP response headers.

How can I get the `Content-Type` using JavaScript after the image loading.

More specifically, what I need is a function like below.

```
/**
 * @param  {HTMLImageElement} img
 * @return {String}     the content type, e.g. "image/png", "image/svg+xml"
 */
getImgContentType(img) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Could you use `console.log` and find out yourself?

Comment: How are you loading image, just `<img>` tag im HTML or via JS?

Comment: Make a XMLHttpRequest of type `HEAD` to the url of the image.

Comment: .... which is only possible within the limits of CORS, of course :-)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - _"type `HEAD` to the URL of the image"_?

Comment: yes, HEAD is the only option if you don't load image manually with JS

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a XMLHttpRequest of type `HEAD` (type `HEAD` means that the request will only recieve the header data, the image won't be redownloaded):

```
getImgContentType(img) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("HEAD", img.src, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));   // type
            console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")); // size
            // ...
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Just note that not all servers implement `HEAD` requests.

Comment: .... and the server needs to accept the cross origin request (CORS) by sending the respective header information

Comment: @devnull69 I've been using this method almost every day, and I've never come across a CORS problem. I think CORS only apply when the method is `GET` or when the file requested is something other than images, videos, ... you know the staff that are accessed from anywhere.

Comment: @devnull69 No need to worry for HEAD requests (if you don't send custom reqest headers, which we will not in this case).

Comment: @Kaiido yes exactly! the only problem is that is the server does not implement HEAD requests.

Comment: Then he can just make the same exact request as the img element did, it will use cache anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what to do if I don't want to send the XHR request? The <img> dom node was added in html document, and when the browser opens the html document, the img will be loaded automatically by the browser. So sending a XHR to get the content-type seems an extra cost. And if there are thousands of imgs, to detect all img types, the overhead would be quite large.

Comment: @GentleMint HEAD request are smaller in size than GET requests. GET requests contain the metadata(size, content-tyle, ...) and the actual data (the image).  HEAD resuest only the metadata get downloaded (few bytes). But it depend on network speed and a lot of other things so it may be slow, but it's the only way.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to make HEAD request to fetch headers. Here is another simple version using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API could look like this:

```
getImgContentType (img) {
  return fetch(img.src, { method: 'HEAD' })
    .then(response => response.headers.get('Content-type'))
}
```

And usage would be:

```
obj.getImgContentType().then(type => {
  console.log(type)
})
```

Also note, that `getImgContentType`'s interface needs to be asynchronous. It's convenient to return promise.